# How to return string value of items inside file using fs and promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, promise

i have a doubt, i have this code in js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

fs.readFileAsync = function(filename) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
            if (err) 
                reject(err); 
            else 
                resolve(data);
        });
     });
};

function constructStringArray(nameArray) {
    var i = 1;
    fs.readFileAsync("./input.txt").then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Something goes wrong");
    });
}
constructStringArray("test");
```

And this code returns me this value: .

How can i make to return strings like this:
Adria
Joan
Papo

Thank you.

Comment: What's inside that `input.txt` file? Also, have you tried `console.log(value.toString())`?

Comment: It returns buffer, you can convert it to string like `value.toString()`

Comment: OMG, Thank you!, i don't see it sorry